# Validating a clustering document

Tags: java, validation, clustering

My goal in the method is to write a simple clustering program that determines if a clustering document is valid based on these rules:

- All clusterings start with `<` and end with `>`.
  Every start clustering `<something>` must be followed (eventually) by an end clustering `</something>`.
- Clusterings must be properly nested as follows `<a><b>data</b></a>`. This is not allowed: <strike>`<a><b>data</a></b>`</strike>.
- The first clustering of the document is the **root clustering**. The document can have only one root clustering (and corresponding end clustering). Everything else must be enclosed inside the root's start and end clusterings. In the example above, `<songdata>` is the root.
- All clusterings are **case-sensitive**. This means **`<song>`** is not the same as **`<Song>`**, which is not the same as **`<SONG>`**, etc.
- Start and end clusterings do not have to occur on the same line, but each clustering can **not** be broken between two lines. So you **can't** do this:

  ```
  <dura
  tion>
  ```
- The clustering name can contain **only letters**.
- Everything that is not a clustering is considered document data.
- Extra white space is ignored. Thus, **`<a> <b>data</b> </a>`**  is the same as  **`<a><b>data</b></a>`**.

This is the code that I'm using to accomplish my task:

```
data=in.readLine();
++line;
nextDataValue=data.trim();//removes whitespace from both ends
if(nextDataValue.charAt(0)!='<') error("No enclosing root pillow.", line);//Everything else must be enclosed inside the root's start and end pillows.
    StringTokenizer tokenizer1=new StringTokenizer(nextDataValue, ">");
    while(tokenizer1.hasMoreTokens())
    {
        nextDataValue=tokenizer1.nextToken();//extract each data element of the string
        if (nextDataValue.indexOf('<') == -1) break;// no < in line, so get next
        pillow=nextDataValue.substring(nextDataValue.indexOf('<')+1, nextDataValue.length());// pillow=get < to > exclusive in nextDataValue
        if(pillow.charAt(0)!='/')
        {
            stack.push(pillow);//start
            start_pillow_pushed=true;
        }
        else if(pillow.charAt(0)=='/')//end
        {
            start_pillow_pushed=false;
            if(!stack.isEmpty()) 
            {
                if(!nextDataValue.equals(stack.pop())) error("Mismatched start pillow "+nextDataValue+">", line);// For each pillow you find, pop the stack to see if the matching start pillow is there.
            }
            else error("Missing start pillow "+nextDataValue+">", line);//empty stack
        }
    }

for(; (data=in.readLine())!=null;)
{
++line;
nextDataValue=data.trim();//removes whitespace from both ends
if(nextDataValue.charAt(0)!='<') error("No enclosing root pillow.", line);//Everything else must be enclosed inside the root's start and end pillows.
    StringTokenizer tokenizer2=new StringTokenizer(nextDataValue, ">");
    while(tokenizer2.hasMoreTokens())
    {
        nextDataValue.trim();
        nextDataValue=tokenizer2.nextToken();//extract each data element of the string
        if (nextDataValue.indexOf('<') == -1) break;// no < in line, so get next
        pillow=nextDataValue.substring(nextDataValue.indexOf('<')+1, nextDataValue.length());// pillow=get < to > exclusive in nextDataValue
        if(pillow.charAt(0)!='/')
        {
            stack.push(pillow);//start
            start_pillow_pushed=true;
        }
        else if(pillow.charAt(0)=='/')//end
        {
            start_pillow_pushed=false;
            if(!stack.isEmpty()) 
            {
                if(!nextDataValue.equals(stack.pop())) error("Mismatched start pillow "+nextDataValue+">", line);// For each pillow you find, pop the stack to see if the matching start pillow is there.
            }
            else error("Missing start pillow "+nextDataValue+">", line);//empty stack
        }
    }
}
if(stack.isEmpty()) System.out.println("Input clustering document is valid.");//reports the document is valid based on the clustering rules above
else error("Missing end pillow for "+nextDataValue+">", line);
```

Please indicate what can be improved in this.

Comment: The headline of your question.

Comment: 1/ It may not be homework, but it does feel like it since you're basically writing a parser of a subset of XML (if it is homework, please add the [tag:homework] tag). 2/ "clustering" is surprising choice for talking about what is [an element](http://www.w3.org/TR/1998/REC-DOM-Level-1-19981001/level-one-core.html#ID-745549614). (And [clustering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clustering) already has a lot of meanings.) 3/ What is a pillow?

Comment: +1 to everything @Cygal said. I would just add that you can probably make the code cleaner and more concise by using recursion, rather than an explicit stack.

Answer (score 11):

Thanks for sharing your code! Let's see what can be improved.

### Design

You're mixing a lot of things in your code. This makes it difficult to read and write. It also violates the [Single Responsibility Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle). I'd recommend separating those three "responsibilities" in different functions/classes. The easiest way to do it is to have three functions:

1. The handling of multiple lines (String -> String)

   ```
   readfile("<a> <b>\ndata</b>\n </a>") == "<a> <b> data</b>  </a>"
   ```
2. The tokenizing of the tag names (String -> List)

   ```
   tokenize("<a> <b> data</b>  </a>") == ["<a>", "<b>", "data", "</b>", "</a>"]
   ```
3. The use of the stack to ensure that the document is valid (List -> bool)

   ```
   isValid(["<a>", "<b>", "data", "</b>", "</a>"]) == true
   ```

If you're worried about performance (you shouldn't, most XML parsers keep the whole tree in memory), you can always group the first and second function in a Iterator, which will decouple the reading/tokenizing from the validation logic, and you will still be doing stream-based parsing. This simply reduces memory usage, and can be a bit faster.

### Code

1. You're [repeating yourself](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) before and after the loop. Use a `do { } while()` construct to avoid this issue.
2. Be careful about your indentation. For example, `if(nextDataValue.charAt(0)!='<') error("No enclosing root pillow.", line);` is not the starting of a block, and you should not indent what's after. Java IDEs can indent code if you don't know how to do it.
3. When checking for `pillow.charAt(0)`, don't use `else if` but `else` for the second block. It makes it clear that the two conditions cover every case.
4. The `start_pillow_pushed` variable is not used anywhere. Never keep dead code around, it simply confuses the reader.